# Getting an error when accessing a submenu page which i've created in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, submenu

I've created a submenu page in wordpress, when I'm accessing it, the following error occurs:

> Sorry you are not allowed to access the page.

I've already tried changing permissions and `WP_DEBUG`, but that doesn't solve the issue.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'b2b_user_management',11);

function b2b_user_management(){
  add_submenu_page('b2b_user_management','B2B User Management', 'B2B User Management','edit_themes','b2b_user_management','b2b_user_management_function');
}

function b2b_user_management_function(){
    include('managing_user.php');
}
```

How can I write the code, so I can access the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this

```
function b2b_user_management_function(){
       echo "Helllo";
    }
```

and access page by below link

```
http://your-website-url/wp-admin/admin.php?page=b2b_user_management
```

Comment: Yes "hello" got printed. Then?

Comment: @MananAhuja Now you can add your code in `function b2b_user_management_function()`  according your requirement.

Comment: Cool, I sorted it out and It's working. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Awesome, the only working solution I found after deep digging, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
add_action('admin_menu',  'b2b_user_management');
function b2b_user_management() {
    add_menu_page(
        'User Management',
        'User Management',
        'edit_themes',
        'user-management',
        'user_management',
        plugins_url('your-plugin-folder/images/logo.png')
    );  
    add_submenu_page(
        'B2B User Management', 
        'B2B User Management', 
        'edit_themes', 
        'b2b-user-management', // This should be your page slug
        'b2b_user_management' // This should be your function name in 'managing_user.php' file
    ); 

}
define('ROOTDIR_PATH', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__));
require_once(ROOTDIR_PATH . 'managing_user');
```

Comment: It doesn't seem working. I am getting this issue again. Nothing is happening.